# ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index при создании Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть семь переменных: DATEhh, DECDATEhh, HAEhh, HANhh, HK2hh, HAE_TCOMPhh, HAN_TCOMPhh.
Все семь переменных имеют тип:  class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
Все семь имеют shape (48,1)
При создании DataFrame, который запишется в файл:

```
sm=pd.DataFrame({'DATE':DATEhh,'DECDATE':DECDATEhh,'HAE':HAEhh,'HAN':HANhh,'HK2':HK2hh,'HAE_TCOMP':HAE_TCOMPhh,'HAN_TCOMP':HAN_TCOMPhh})
```

выдается ошибка:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Каждую из 7 переменных можно вывести на экран (по 48 значений), т.е. скалярами они не являются. Похоже, что проблема в размерности каждой переменной (48, 1), а должно быть (48, ), но тип переменных dataframe, а не series потому ravel использовать не получится.
Можно записать данные в качестве словаря:

```
my_dict={'DATE':DATEhh,'DECDATE':DECDATEhh,'HAE':HAEhh,'HAN':HANhh,'HK2':HK2hh,'HAE_TCOMP':HAE_TCOMPhh,'HAN_TCOMP':HAN_TCOMPhh}  


sm=pd.DataFrame.from_dict([my_dict])
sm.to_csv('hour_data.csv', index=False)
```

Но тогда значения всех семи переменных записываются последовательно в один столбец, кроме того в файл добавляются служебные знаки, поэтому тоже не подходит. Как избавиться от ошибки? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k: v.iloc[:, 0] for k,v in my_dict.items()})
```